# How to change Text view Color when we select that text view it should be highlighted

Tags: android

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/enEnV.jpg)I am trying to change the  Background color of  textview when i select Textview  that should be highlighted or visible .(Like in flipkart when we select size or color then it is Highlighted which size we have chosen like that only i also want )

i want like this

Comment: "when I select Textview" - when you click it? In addition, please add your relevant code

Comment: Hi! Could you maybe add some screenshots of what your app is doing now, and what you would like it to do?

Comment: yea when i click it

Comment: i havev added screenshot can u please check it

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    // on the click of textview
      TextView textView=findViewById(R.id.name);
     textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textView.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorAccent));
            textView.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        }
    });
```

Comment: it is showing this error:-    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.TextView.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
        at com.arvi.e_comm.Activity.DetailsItemActivity.onCreate(DetailsItemActivity.java:102)

Comment: make sure you have initialised your text view by using textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.name);

Comment: yea i have initialized

Answer (score 0):

You can also give color like

```
 TextView textView=findViewById(R.id.tv);
     textView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            textView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor(#hexcodeofcolor));
        }
    });
```